# Java collections that spool to disk

Tags: java

I'm running out of memory in Java due to some very large Lists and Sets built up over the course of a transaction and iterated over just once at transaction's end.  Are there any libraries that provide Java collections that can spool their serializable contents to disk when the collection size exceeds a given threshold?

Comment: Not exactly what you might be searching for, take a look at Hadoop http://hadoop.apache.org/

Comment: Is there a reason that you are not using a standard RDBMS for this?  In one way, it's the definition of what you are asking about.  Even a lightweight ones like h2db, sqlite would be up to most tasks.

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like [ehcache](http://ehcache.org) and its overflowToDisk option

Comment: as I know Ehcache doesn't have logic that poll(get+remove) elements from the cache, according to documentation I see only #get() methods.
Maybe you know how can I implement such functionality using ehcache?

Answer (score 4):

I won't post you example code because it would become too long, but this is how I done it before:

1. Extend `LinkedBlockingQueue`.
2. Override its `offer`, `put`, `poll`, `take` and `remove` methods. *Example*: if superclass' `offer` returns  false (capacity reached), *then* I would start serializing to disk.
3. Likewise, in `take` implementation, you check if you have any present elements in memory at all, and, if not, *then* you start reading from disk (and removing the first record read because it will now reside in memory; or you can read records in batches, of course).
4. Assign each instance of such a queue a filesystem-safe identifier, so that I can use it to create filesystem-safe file name for it. Also, to take it further, I would probably use current user's home directory as a place for these queues to be serialized onto disk.

That way, 99% of your disk-serialized queue is ready, and you only put your extra functionality at exactly the right spots. You would need to thoroughly read the documentation of Java's `BlockingQueue` interface, but hey, it's worth your time because you will only add that little extra bit of functionality you need, rather than writing the whole thing from scratch.

Hope this helps.